# Upgrading UrbanAirship Library from 8.3.2 to 9.0.0

Tags: android, push-notification, android-manifest, urbanairship.com, android-push-notification

Push notifications are not working correctly for me because I am using an old Urban Airship (now re-branded simply as Airship) SDK. I am using Version 8.3 and I need to upgrade to Version 9.0.0. I am reading https://github.com/urbanairship/android-library/blob/master/documentation/migration/migration-guide.md for instructions about how to upgrade. I found this section that is relevant to my case:

> **UrbanAirship Library 8.x to 9.0.0**
>
> **GCM**
>
> All of the GCM classes have been moved into the package `com.urbanairship.push.gcm`. If you have manually added the `GcmPushReceiver` or `UAInstanceIDListenerService` in your manifest, please update the entries.

I found two `AndroidManifest.xml` files in my source code:

1. C:\Users[path]\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

   `<!-- Optional: Receives push and registration events from the Urban Airship SDK. -->`

   ```
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="com.urbanairship.push.CHANNEL_UPDATED"/>
       <action android:name="com.urbanairship.push.OPENED"/>
       <action android:name="com.urbanairship.push.DISMISSED"/>
       <action android:name="com.urbanairship.push.RECEIVED"/>

       <category android:name="${applicationId}"/>
   </intent-filter>
   ```
2. C:\Users[path]\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.urbanairship.android\urbanairship-sdk\8.3.2\AndroidManifest.xml

``

```
    <service
        android:name="com.urbanairship.push.UAInstanceIDListenerService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="-999" >
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.urbanairship.push.GcmPushReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="-999" >
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**Question 1.** When the instructions ask to update entries `in your manifest`, does it refer to the first or second `AndroidManifest.xml` file that I listed above? I assume it could only refer to `C:\Users[path]\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml` because `C:\Users\[path]\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.urbanairship.android\urbanairship-sdk\8.3.2\AndroidManifest.xml` would be automatically generated when compiling the app.

**Question 2.** When the instructions say that `in your manifest, please update the entries`, does it mean to remove the manually added lines because the package `com.urbanairship.push.gcm` already includes `GcmPushReceiver` and `UAInstanceIDListenerService` and it would automatically be taking care of it?

Thank you.

**UPDATE 1:** Looking at the Android.Manifest.xml file at https://github.com/urbanairship/android-library/blob/master/urbanairship-gcm/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml, mine should look like that once I upgrade to Version 9.7.1, correct? Then I should include in my project the files/classes listed at https://github.com/urbanairship/android-library/tree/master/urbanairship-gcm/src/main/java/com/urbanairship/push/gcm. Correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I am using this in my `build.gradle (Module: app)`:

```
// Urban Airship SDK
//compile 'com.urbanairship.android:urbanairship-sdk:8.3.+'
implementation 'com.urbanairship.android:urbanairship-fcm:9.7.1'
```

I also had to do the following though, to get rid of some errors I initially saw when using `implementation 'com.urbanairship.android:urbanairship-fcm:9.7.1'`:

1. Installed `Android SDK Platform 28 (platforms;android-28)
2. Replaced `compileSdkVersion 23` with `compileSdkVersion 28` in `build.gradle (Module: app)

[image]
[image]

I also used `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart...` just in case, to make sure everything was refreshed after I modified the `build.gradle (Module: app)` file.